# Convert pdf to a single page editable html

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js, pdf-to-html

I have been trying to **convert a pdf file to a single nice html page**.After surfing about it.
The solutions I have got are little bit lacking to my requirements.As I have to create individual html pages for say about 200 pdf files.As online converters might not be a leading solution. So I tried the following solutions along with the requirements not being fulfilled.

- **[embed tag of html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813)**

  `+`embeds a pdf into html page nicely.

  `-`HTML page is not editable since it simply embeds the pdf to html page.
- **[pdftohtml](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/linux/utilities/file/pdftohtml.html)**

  `+`Converts the pdf to single html page.

  `-`the look is not very nice.
- **[pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)**

  `+`Converts the pdf to html page with a readable look.

  `-`HTML page is not editable.
- **[jpdf2html](http://www.idrsolutions.com/pdf2html/)**

  `+`Converts the pdf to single html page with a nice look and html css.

  `-`It creats a big folder contaning images for thumbnails and html page for a single page in pdf that might not be feasible for large   number of pdf files.

From where can I improve the output..

Comment: jpdf2html by idr solutions has an option to inline images and the thumbnails is easily configurable to switch off. There is some documentation including http://www.idrsolutions.com/configuring-the-pdf-to-html5-converter/

Comment: FlexPaper reflow converts your document to editable html and separates each pdf page in its separate file. Its in beta but the output is already far ahead of many of the other options

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/download/

Answer (score 2):

FlexPaper has a desktop publisher mode called Elements that has the ability to convert pdf to editable elements- worth a look

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/download

Answer (score 1):

use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#html) to convert PDF to HTML 
however ghostscript can provide you with an improvements to your output PDF

Comment: well thanks but here i want to convert it into an editable html page which should contain a decent & readable graphics.for example one should be able to edit the html contents of the page like text and alignments. as given by jpdf2html.