# Is it possible to generate pdf from html having embedded pdf in it using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, iframe, wkhtmltopdf

I am using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) for generating pdf from html, its working fine. But its not working when we embedd pdf through iframe in html. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: You might want to refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586524/convert-pdf-to-a-single-page-editable-html

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I tried hard to find solution to that and to resolve that I have embedded the corresponding image instead of that pdf. Now ,its working well.

Comment: You may use GhostScript to convert pdf to image